# JMS QUEUE application as jar or ear

Tags: java, jboss, jar, jms, ear

This might be a stupid question.
I have two EJB project in my eclipse workspace, one is MDB and the other is Session bean.
And my client is successfully send messages to the queue in localhost. Now i want to put my client to call the queue from a remote location. Before I do this do I have to make an EAR combining the above two ejb project?

(I couldn't run my client successfully from remote location to address the jms queue, the problem might be calling the queue. I found many helps for this but all of them are talking about ear file, but I have two jar files)

PS: or is it possible to do this with jar files, I think yes, but do not know the right way
Please guide me
(server - jboss 5)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past, I had a number of web apps, producing JMS messages to be processed by some JMS beans (basically sending email). I did not deploy any EAR files, rather I did this.

1. webapps deployed as war files.
2. JMS app deployed as a jar file, just containing the JMB classes.
3. To add the plumbing, deploy the queue JNDI descriptor in the the deploy directory.
4. Makesure the JNDI descriptor for your queues is defined in the web.xml.

An EAR file is a 'convenience' to allow a one step deployment of all the artifacts that make up your 'system', but you can deploy the individual components (jar files, war files, descriptors), also, your JMX console and log output will tell you what is being deployed.